# How to add combobox to DataGridView by bounding database datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

In my application I want to add combobox to DataGridView.

I use this code:

By DataGridView column collection property add combobox column

Use in .cs code as below

```
 datagridview1.autogeneratedcolumn = false;
 datagridview.datasource = datatable;
```

It show combobox in DataGridView but it did not dropdown. Means it doesn't have items (I check for datatable.. it contains all items)

Comment: You have to bind the dropdown first with the items.

Comment: Post your code. What is the datasource. Your `DataTable` schema etc.

Comment: Debug and check if you are getting any data in your "datatable"

Answer (score 0):

After you define your datasource you have to bind the data to the gridview
add this line after your second line

```
    datagridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: I did not get "databind()" to datagriedview ...I get DataBindings() which give me error thtat cannot use like method

Answer (score 0):

Your control names are different too. Try this

```
datagridview1.AutoGeneratedColumn = false;
datagridview1.DataSource = datatable;
datagridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I did not get databind() property

Answer (score 0):

In one of my apps, I bind an enum as a datasource to my combo box column. Here is the code I use to bind it (in the load event).

```
if (dgv.Columns[COL_INDEX] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
            {
                ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgv.Columns[COL_INDEX]).DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();
            }
```

As for the row data, I use a binding source.

You can set a binding source to an object by selecting the datagridview, go to properties (F4), DataSource, Add Project Data Source, Object, select your object. The columns will be created and you can change the desired column to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, and the above code will set your choices.

Comment: how to pass datatable value to enum.?????..my data is dynamic. I dont know the values whatever get from database